# Java matcher unable to finding last group

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying regex after a long time. I'm not sure if the issue is with regex or the logic.

```
String test = "project/components/content;contentLabel|contentDec";
String regex = "(([A-Za-z0-9-/]*);([A-Za-z0-9]*))";

Map<Integer, String> matchingGroups = new HashMap<>();

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
//System.out.println("Input: " + test + "\n");
//System.out.println("Regex: " + regex + "\n");
//System.out.println("Matcher Count: " + matcher.groupCount() + "\n");
if (matcher != null && matcher.find()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
         System.out.println(i + " ->  " + matcher.group(i) + "\n");
    }
}
```

I was expecting the above to give me the output as below:

```
0 ->  project/components/content;contentLabel|contentDec
1 ->  project/components/content
2 ->  contentLabel|contentDec
```

But when running the code the group extractions are off.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: On executing this, I'm still unable to get the last group information. This is the output I see now -------->>
0 ->  project/components/content;contentLabel|contentDec  
1 ->  project/components/content

Comment: @Sal no need to escape `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues:

1. You're missing `|` in your second character class.
2. You have an unnecessary capture group around the whole regex.
3. When outputting the groups, you need to use `<= matcher.groupCount()` because `matcher.group(0)` is reserved for the whole match, so your capture groups are in `group(1)` and `group(2)`.

This will work:

```
String test = "project/components/content;contentLabel|contentDec";
String regex = "([A-Za-z0-9-/]*);([A-Za-z0-9|]*)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
if (matcher != null && matcher.find()) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
         System.out.println(i + " ->  " + matcher.group(i) + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! This worked. Great explanation, especially the 3rd point. Thank you!